# How to push text to the left (out of the box) and make it hidden?

Tags: css

See the top of http://www.joopvos.nl/acmplus/ (column) ... at the right the line of text is cropped as wanted ... and at the left I want the same ... but can it be done with CSS?

HTML:

```
<h1 id="site-name">ACM<span>+</span> ACM<span>+</span> ACM<span>+</span> ACM<span>+</span> ACM<span>+</span></h1>
```

CSS:

```
h1#site-name {
padding: 16px 0 20px 0;
font-size: 4em;
line-height: 100%;
font-family: 'MuseoSans500','Lucida Grande', 'sans serif';
color: #dcdcdc;
font-weight: normal;
float: left;
display: inline;
background-color: transparent;
text-transform: uppercase;
white-space: pre; /* everything on one line! */
overflow: hidden;
width: 700px;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
text-indent: -1000px;
```

That'll pull it off screen, to the left.